# How to CLEAR STATE in redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, state, redux-toolkit

This is my Code, But when we click other component this state remain same after refresh its OK

```js
[getOrderList.fulfilled]:(state, action) => {
  state.getUsersOrderList = [...state.getUsersOrderList, action.payload];
},
```

I Want to clear my previous state on payload

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "clearing the state"?

Comment: Hi RubenSmn
I want to reset it so it cant  appear in another component

Comment: Then you could set it to an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by only using the `action.payload` in your array

```js
[getOrderList.fulfilled]:(state, action) => {
  state.getUsersOrderList = [action.payload];
},
```

Comment: Hi  @RubenSmn Thanks for the reply
but I have a load more button so that I can restore the previous state, But this state data are shown in other components also, when I refresh its ok